# Deleting duplicates in multidimension array?

Tags: php, duplicates, combinations

I want to delete duplicate in multidimension array. My array is like this:

```
a => array (a,b), b => array (b,a), c => array (a,b,c)
```

I have tried using a for loop and unset but it changes my index. Is there a simple function how to check for duplicates values and delete the entire key? I generate my multidimensional array with all combinations from a string abcdef?

Output should be: `a => array (a,b), c => array (a,b,c)`. Key b is removed from the array.

The function needs to check every value in the keys against every other key-values. It's about removing all permutations.

I have tried this but it destroys my index and the whole array gets messed up:

```
            for($i=0;$i<=count($newarr[$i]);++$i)
        {

            for($k=0;$k<=count($newarr[$i]["grp"]);++$k)
            {
                $plz=$newarr[$i]["grp"][$k]["plz"];
                $rank=$newarr[$i]["grp"][$k]["rank"];
                for($j=$i+1;$j<=count($newarr);++$j)
                {
                    if (!$skip[$j])
                    {
                        for ($l=0;$l<=count($newarr[$j]["grp"]);++$l)
                        {
                            if ($plz==$newarr[$j]["grp"][$l]["plz"]
                                && $rank==$newarr[$j]["grp"][$l]["rank"] 
                                )
                            {
                                unset($newarr[$j]["grp"][$l]);
                                //$newarr=array_values($newarr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using `unset()` won't change your index at all, can you show us your current code ?

Comment: I need to remove all permutations but a for loop and unset doesn't work. I have read you need to reindex the array and I have tried array_values to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output ?

Comment: Can you send me an array initial value?. I want to know structure of array with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$array = array( 'a' => array(a,b), 'b' => array(b,a), 'c' => array(a,b,c));
$arrTemp = array();               

foreach($array as $key => $innerArr)
{
    foreach($array as $key1 => $innerArr1)  // 
    {
        if($key != $key1)   // compare if key is not same
        {
            sort($innerArr);    // sort array
            sort($innerArr1);   // sort array

            if($innerArr == $innerArr1 && !in_array($key1,$arrTemp))    // check is array is same but array key is diffrent
            {
                unset($array[$key1]);       // unset array
                $arrTemp[] = $key;      // make entry for not to compare further
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you look at my code, please? I have updated my question?

Comment: Add the end of the inner loop you need also to add the key from the outer loop to arrTemp otherwise it makes the solution to work endless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So here's how you may get this job done:

```
$array = array('a' => array('a', 'b'), 'b' => array('b', 'a'), 'c' => array('a', 'b', 'c')); // Test data

$temp = $array; // temp array
foreach($array as $i => $o){
    array_multisort($temp[$i]); // sorting the multi temp array
}

foreach($temp as $k => &$v){
    foreach($temp as $m => &$n){
        if($k != $m && $v == $n){unset($array[$m], $temp[$m]);} // removing duplicates
    }
}

print_r($array); // printing results
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

)
```